# Android ViewPager with Databinding and MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, android-viewpager, android-databinding

I have implemented data binding for simple screens with MVVM i.e for the login screen, for the listing screen.

So, I know about MVVM + data binding in android.

But, in my app, I have to do the same for ViewPager which is using FragmentStatePager Adapter and it includes a total of 3 Fragments.

I have googled it to achieve such a thing, but not getting what I need.

We can not pass any data binding property(ies) in the ViewPager tag, Will you please guide me :

**How can We implement the same (databinding + MVVM) for ViewPager?**

Comment: You can create BindingAdapters to achieve such functionality. Refer here for more info: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters

Answer (score 1):

**Activity Class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        {
            
            @BindView(R.id.view_pager) ViewPager viewPager;
        
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.layout_name);
                ButterKnife.bind(this);
                viewPager.setAdapter(doctorListMenu());
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                 tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {}
        
                    @Override
                    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) { }
        
                    @Override
                    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) { }
                });
            }
        
            private ViewPagerAdapter fragmentsList()
            {
        
                ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
                adapter.addFragment(new DoctorListFragment(), "FragmentA");
                adapter.addFragment(new DoctorListFragment(), "FragmentB");
                adapter.addFragment(new DoctorListFragment(), "FragmentC");
        
                return adapter;
            }
        }
```

> **Fragment class**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment
    {
        private LayoutYourLayoutName binding;
        private YOUR_VIEW_MODEL viewModel;
    
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
            binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                    inflater, R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
            View view = binding.getRoot();
            viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(YOUR_VIEW_MODEL.class);
            binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
            binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
            return view;
        }
    
    }
```

> **Fragment adapter class**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager) {
        super(supportFragmentManager);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return mList.get(i);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mList.add(fragment);
        mTitleList.add(title);
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mTitleList.get(position);
    }

}
```

Comment: you mean we need to bind for inner fragment screens. No need to much worry about activity screen (which has viewpager in its xml) ?

Comment: I dont want to use ButterKnife.

Comment: If you don't want use butter knife then ignore it, you can do this with out butter knife, 
viewPager xml will added in MainActivity,

Comment: So which property do we need to use inside viewpager tag to binding ?

Comment: You just need to add a fragment class in FragmentAdapter and set this adapter with viewPager

Comment: ViewMdel class ?

Comment: This is an example of ViewModel class.


public class ViewModelExample extends AndroidViewModel 
{

    public ViewModelExample(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
    }
 
 //do what ever you want 
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225760/discussion-between-atik-faysal-and-jaimin-modi).